# Cannot install Bioperl Moduals

Tags: bioperl

1. Building BioPerl
2. Reading skip patterns from 'INSTALL.SKIP'.
3. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
4. ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/bin'
5. Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/bin'

   ### 6. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I cannot install bioperl on my linux,It happened when I run command 11 below:
 7. git clone https://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live.git
 8. cd bioperl-live
 9. perl Build.PL
 10. ./Build test
 11. ./Build install

Comment: The issue is right there in (5): permissions. Try:

    'sudo ./Build install'

Comment: Linux version 4.4.6-201.fc22.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2) (GCC) )

Answer (score 0):

> Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/bin'
>   Looks like you need to run the build script as root, so use the 'sudo' command like

```
sudo ./Build install
```

On a separate note, is there a specific reason you need to compile Bioperl from source? Using your distro's package manager would be the easiest way to go about getting bioperl running with the least number of headaches. Check out https://bioperl.org/INSTALL.html for a number of options for installing.